# Finding occurences in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, duplicates

I'm trying to count duplicates in a list, I wrote this code, but it does not seem to work. Anyone got any idea about how to fix it? P.S I'm avoiding using libraries

```
string = "btu got punished by btu lol lol"

value = string.split()

aList = []
duplicates = []
countedDict = {}

for i in value:
    if i not in aList:
        aList.append(i)
    else:
        duplicates.append(i)

for i in aList:
    if i in duplicates:
        duplicates.append(i)

for x in duplicates:
    countedDict[x] = len([x])
```

Comment: For your info: the question got downvoted and closed because "it does not seem to work" is not an acceptable error description. The rest of your question is mostly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a dictionary comprehension:

```
string = "btu got punished by btu lol lol"
print({k: string.count(k) for k in string.split()})
```

Output:

```
{'btu': 2, 'got': 1, 'punished': 1, 'by': 1, 'lol': 2}
```

Or if you can use `collections` module, use:

```
from collections import Counter
string = "btu got punished by btu lol lol"
print(Counter(string.split()))
```

Comment: Your dictionary comprehension takes `O(N^2)` time complexity.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
string = "btu got punished by btu lol lol"
occur = {}
value = string.split()
for i in value:
    c = 0
    for j in value:
        if i ==j:
            c+=1
    occur[i]=c
```

Output:

```
{'btu': 2, 'got': 1, 'punished': 1, 'by': 1, 'lol': 2}
```